# Javascript in SSRS not handling number sign correctly

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using some JavaScript code in SSRS to open a link in a new window on a report.  The report links point to file locations on a server.  The code I am using within Reporting Services for the link is:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('"+ "file:" & Replace(Fields!FilePath.Value,"\","/") + "','_blank'))"
```

This code works just fine when the file name is something 'normal' such as:

```
\\myserver\images\Files\1969\1-000-002_SE 82ND AVE 1_1969.pdf
```

However, when there are special characters (at least # for sure), I get an error message.  This is what happens.  An example file name would be:

```
\\myserver\images\Files\1978\1-001-003_SE 82nd AVE #12 1_1978.pdf
```

In this case what gets returned as the URL is:

```
\\myserver\images\Files\1978\1-001-003_SE 82nd AVE
```

As can be seen, the URL is cut off at the first instance of the number sign.  If I copy the shortcut for the offending link, this is what I get:

```
javascript:void(window.open('file://myserver/images/Files/1978/1-001-003_SE%2082nd%AVE%20#12%201_1978.pdf','_blank'))
```

It appears that the JavaScript is encoding the file path correctly but something is getting lost in translation between the JavaScript code and the URL.

I am unable to change the file names so I need to come up with a way to work with the special characters.  I have tried using EncodeURI() but could not figure out how to format it correctly in SSRS to work with the existing JavaScript.

Any ideas would be welcomed.

Comment: Just a question but what happens if you omit the # char from the filename?

Comment: As inferred above, the page is rendered successfully.  However, I am not able to change the file names.

Answer (score 0):

URLs will recognize the HTML character numbers. So, outside of your JavaScript, use an SSRS replace function for each special character you expect to find, replacing each with its corresponding HTML number code. For instance, a pound sign is %23; and a space is %20.

Note, I have some pages that use pound signs to split out URL parameters, and this **does NOT** seem to work in those cases. However, it might work in your situation. To try this, change your function to the following:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('"+ "file:" & Replace(Replace(Fields!FilePath.Value,"\","/"),"#","%23") + "','_blank'))"
```

In case this does work for you, you can find more of these codes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).